# Torr file editor will automatically restore

Tags: configuration

I want to modify the configuration of the Torrc of the Tor browser. Before the Tor browser 12 version, the Torrc file is set to read only attributes and can be used normally, but the Torrc file is set in Tor Browser 12 version to read only attributes and cannot connect.

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your .torrc file before every start of Tor browser, because, the file will read, but overwritten by starting Tor browser.

Set the file to read only, will prevent the Tor browser to work.

So you have to edit the .torrc file before every start of Tor or you overwrite the existing .torrc file before every Tor start, by one prepared one.